# How does one go about making a hangman game where the computer shows you your progress in Python?

Tags: python, loops, printing

I'm trying to make a Hangman game in Python but I lack the knowledge of several things it seems. This code below is a rough draft on what I got so far. The idea here is using words from a text file, separating them into a list and then taking a random entry on that list to use as the word for the game. After that, it takes an input from the user on a letter: if the input is in the list, it should print a the word, but turning the letters that weren't guessed yet into "_". So, for example: ____a _. The problem is, I don't know how to do this and it's very confusing. As you can see below, I was trying to use a "for" loop.

```py
import random
import string

# Opening the text file that contains the words that are going to be used in the game
with open('words.txt') as file:
    text = file.read()
    words = list(map(str, text.split()))
    result = random.choice(words)
    list_of_letters = list(result)

attempts = 1
for attempts in range(6):
    pick = input("Pick a letter: ")
    if pick in list_of_letters:
        print(pick)
    else:
        print("_")

#Here is supposed to be what you get as a result when you lose, I want to keep track of the progress like __a__a__, for example.
else:
    print("You lost! The word was", result, "\n Here's your progress: ", )
```

Comment: You should use a `while` loop as your main game loop. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a few more tutorials in python you have made some minor errors in terms of efficiency and methodology. But to answer your question I made this example of a hangman game. Hopefully you can learn from it

My `words.txt` file looks like this `these are some words`

```
# String or str() is a primitive type in python. You don't need to import it. 
import random


# Opening the text file that contains the words that are going to be used in the game
with open('words.txt') as file:

    # Here I read the file, replace newlines ('\n') with a space and then split the entire thing.
    words = file.read().replace('\n', ' ').split(' ')


# function to grab a new word and list of letters
def new_choice(words):

    res = random.choice(words)

    l_of_letters = list(res)

    return res, l_of_letters


# function to evaluate the pick and manage progress
def check_pick(l_of_letters, pick, progress):

    new_progress = []

    match = False

    # if you have already guessed the letter it returns immediately
    if pick in progress:

        print('You have already guessed that letter!')

        return progress, False, True

    for letter in l_of_letters:
        
        # if the letter has not been guessed previously
        if letter not in progress:
            
            # see if it matches the pick
            if pick == letter:
                
                # if it does return a successful match and add it to new_progress
                match = True
             
                new_progress.append(pick)

            else:
                # otherwise add the default underscore 
                new_progress.append('_')
        
        # if it has been guessed before then add it
        else:

            new_progress.append(letter)
    
    # you win if new_progress is all letters 
    w = '_' not in new_progress

    return new_progress, w, match

# function to continually ask for input until it is appropriate
def pick():

    p = input("Pick a letter: ").strip(' ')

    if p == '':

        print('Guess cannot be blank!')

        pick()

    return p

# Beginning of main loop. This will loop forever until break is called in the main loop
while True:

    # get a word choice
    result, list_of_letters = new_choice(words)

    print('_' * len(list_of_letters))
    
    # progress is started as a list of underscores the length of the word
    progress = ['_'] * len(list_of_letters)

    win = False

    attempts = 6
    
    # this nested while loop asks the user to input their choice, evaluates and tracks progress. It does this until you run out of attempts
    while attempts is not 0:

        print('Attempts: ', attempts)
         
        # ask for a pick
        p = pick()

        # check the pick and the progress
        progress, win, match = check_pick(list_of_letters, p[0], progress)
        
        # if check_pick() returns win == True the game is over
        if win:

            print(f'You win! The word was \"{result}\"')

            # this breaks out of the nested while loop    
            break

        # if you haven't won it prints your progress    
        print(''.join(progress))
        
        # if your pick was not a match you lose an attempt
        if not match:

            attempts -= 1

    # if the loop finishes and you haven't won it prints this message
    if not win:

        print(f"You lost! The word was \"{result}\"\nHere's your progress: {''.join(progress)}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem! I really hope this helps your understanding! If this answers your question adequately, please consider making this post the accepted answer :)